# ORA-20000: Schema "HR" does not exist or insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use Oracle 11g express. I try to install sample database HR. From **cmd**

```
sqlplus
system
123456
```

[image]

Error:
[image]

```
Comment created.


Commit complete.

BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(          'HR'                            ,                granularity => 'ALL'            ,                cascade => TRUE                 ,                block_sample => TRUE            ); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Schema "HR" does not exist or insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 3701
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 24470
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 24435
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How I install sample database HR correctly?

Comment: What did you do to start all this? What are your 3 lines on top supposed to mean? Is that a call?

Comment: The script's output contains all the information you need to figure it out for yourself. The first error is expected, because HR does not exist. The second error is not expected, and causes the CREATE USER statement to fail. That causes all the subsequent errors, as they are predicated on HR being created. So: fix the second error and everything else will be sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
create user hr identified by 123456a@
```

**Because user is not created, you are getting other errors.**

To resolve it do either of below

- Remove special character from password. Or use underscores `_` in password.

  ```
  create user hr identified by 123456a
  ```

  **OR**
- Try enclosing password in double quotes. (I am not able to test it now. But if it doesn't work, try first option. I referred this [link](http://www.oradba.ch/2014/06/oracle-passwords-and-special-characters/))

  ```
  create user hr identified by "123456a@"
  ```

Answer (score 9):

Apparently the statement to create the user hr was not executed correctly, and despite that the execution of the hr_main.sql script is not stopped.

This worked for me:

Once as sysdba:

SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
     Session altered.
SQL> create user hr identified  by hr;
     User created.
SQL> drop user hr cascade;
     User droped.
SQL> @?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql
...
User created.
...

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to the PDB container as SYS user before executing the script

```
[oracle@af18354c958e /]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba
Enter password: password

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
SQL> alter session set container = ORCLPDB1
SQL> @hr_main.sql

specify password for HR as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: hr

specify default tablespeace for HR as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: users

specify temporary tablespace for HR as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: temp

specify log path as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/
```

Comment: Probably need a comma at the end of your alter command.
Also, I ended up needing to execute `@?/demo/schema/human_resources/hr_main.sql`

Comment: I don't think we need a comma after alter command. However, we do need to execute hr_main.sql and for doing so, we need to first navigate to the PDB container first as schemas can be created in those containers only and also for execution privileges, we need to first login as sysdba who has the admin privileges. and ya the HR schema will be in the path you mentioned, thanks for noting that

Comment: worked for me on docker container for https://hub.docker.com/u/safrrhmn/content/sub-a4e594f0-53a5-4e62-a1ff-3f878e351868

Comment: Thank you @Nanditha Your answer solved my problem. Just to clarify things: in my case creating `hr` user failed with: `ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name` error and altering session to `ORCLPDB1` helped.